# Dropping observations in SAS based on length

Tags: sas, variable-length

I have a dataset that I'm trying to create tables from but I need to filter out the observations that don't belong in those tables. I'm still learning my way around SAS, so I don't know how to drop the observations using conditions.

Basically I want to drop the observations that have an ID value that is not four digits (in terms of length). Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your ID is character, and you don't consider blanks digits:

`if lengthn(id) ~= 4 then delete;`

If your ID is numeric:

`if 1000 <= id <= 9999 then output;`

Comment: That worked perfectly - don't know why I didn't think of that, thank you!

Comment: The second one could be rewritten `where id between 1000 and 9999;`. `Where` is generally more efficient than `if`.

Comment: Be careful with the `length()` function.  It is ok for this specific example, but it is better practice to use the `lengthn()` function in general.  The difference is `length()` will return a length of 1 for an empty string, whereas the obscure `lengthn()` will return the generally expected value of 0.  A big WTF goes out to whoever designed it this way...

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's a really good point. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is character:

```
where length(id) = 4;
```

If `id` is numeric:

```
where id between 1000 and 9999;
```